# Dropdown menu scroll bar issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a dropdown list looking under the list but it automatically creates scroll bar and inproper height for the list.
[image]

[image]

Though there are 5 elements on the list, it just shows one and the other ones are not shown because of the inproper height, I guess.

This is the css codes;
[image]

**NOTE:** Please inform me if anything is needed

Comment: Post the code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The containing element probably has the default value (`overflow: auto`), so it will create a scroll bar when the content is bigger than it's size.

Just make sure your **containing** element has **`overflow: visible`**.

```css
.div1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div2 {
  overflow: visible;
}

.div3 {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.div4 {
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.space {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="space div1">
  <div class="inner">hidden</div>
</div>

<div class="space div2">
  <div class="inner">visible</div>
</div>

<div class="space div3">
  <div class="inner">scroll</div>
</div>

<div class="space div4">
  <div class="inner">auto</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I delete "overflow-x:auto", it works. Thanks a lot!